# pip install spectrum with no extras

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip, spectrum

I pip-installed `spectrum` which by default installed `matplotlib`. Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/cokelaer/spectrum/blob/master/setup.py), I see that `matplotlib` is in `extras_required`. I wonder how I can install `spectrum` without `matplotlib`.

Comment: Did you try to remove it from the setup.py? It might still install correctly, but you won't be able to use some parts of the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't (shouldn't?), it is also a part of the install [requirements](https://github.com/cokelaer/spectrum/blob/master/requirements.txt).

Having said that, OP uninstalled matplotlib and spectrum still works (at least partially), so perhaps it is not a "true" requirement - and you can either delete it from the requirements file or uninstall matplotlib as done here.

Comment: Oh seriously! Why would someone design it like this?

Comment: @EissaN. It does seem redundant, but no harm I guess. As a rule extras are not installed by default, so be suspicious of the install requirements, especially if they are not listed.

Comment: I use this in docker so it only increases the size of the docker, I did install spectrum and then did `pip uninstall matplotlib` which works fine for me, but I thought there must be a better way! Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: @EissaN. That would mean it is not even really a requirement. I'll add that to the answer.